# Reversing an average when having some information

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, statistics

I know that the average grade for a subject on my year was 2.49(where 2 is failing) and I know there were 133 people taking the course.

How can I best reverse this average? I tried doing something like this:
$$2.49 ≈ \frac{az+bz+cz+dz+ez}{133}$$ $$z \in \{2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5\}\ \ a, b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{N}$$

Which really means $$2.49 ≈ \frac{2a+3b+3.5c+4d+4.5e}{133} $$

But what do I do with that? Is it the right approach? I want to figure out, approximately, how many people failed the subject.

Comment: It could be that noone failed.  It could be that half of everyone failed.  There is almost nothing you can do with the information given to estimate this without massive assumptions which are going to be invalid.

Comment: @JMoravitz There has to be a way to get at least a decent result. We know it's 2.49 so it's within a 100th point of that. There are only 5 possible grades and I know most people failed or got a 3. Not any random distribution of 5 numbers will give 2.49 specifically, especially when we know how many numbers there are. I think I will just write a program and bruteforce it.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the exact distribution of grades of each of the 133 person given the average grade of all them cannot be computed given only the average grade and population size.
However, you can estimate a model of the distribution using known information.
One good estimate model is a Gaussian distribution, which in the case of your problem, can be translated to: in an ordinary classroom, most students will score near the average, a few of them will score very high and another few will score very low.
Now any additional information you know about the classroom, can help you better shape that model and therefore bring more confidence in it. For example, if you know that in your classroom, students tend to get either very high grades or very low grades with very few students getting grades in the middle, it would be then more suitable to take the opposite of the Gaussian distribution.
If you know that the students tends all of them to usually have higher grades than other classrooms, then you can shift your distribution more to the right (higher grades) to capture this information.
Each additional information can help you “better” shape the distribution and therefore providing a better estimate to the real one.

Once you are confident with your estimated distribution, it will then be easy to compute the number of students who got below a specific grade.

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct approach (assuming everyone who failed got 2, which seems a bit strange) but you can't calculate a without knowing b, c, d and e.

In general, you need n linearly independent linear equations to get unique solutions for n variables. Here, you have one linear equation in 5 variables. There are infinitely many combinations of numbers for a,b,c,d and e that solve the equation.

Comment: There's not infinitely many for sure, there are only 5 possible grades.

Comment: But a, b, c, d and e represent the number of people who got {2,3,3.5,4 and 4.5}. But you're right, not infinitely many if they have to be integers between 0 and 133.

Comment: You have another linear equation: a+b+c+d+e = 133. Using the two equations, you can eliminate 2 variables, guess values for three of the variables, and determine the remaining 2. It can't be that no one failed, because then the average would be at least 3. If everyone got 2 or 3, b = 133- a, c = d = e =0. 2a + 3(133-a) = 133*2.49 = 331, so a = 68 and b = 65. If everyone got either 2 oder 4.5: 2a + 4.5(133-a) = 331, so a = 107, e = 26. So between 68 and 107 people failed.